# How to have content scroll over background

Tags: theme-development, customization, front-end

I'm attempting to modify the latest version of the mystique theme, and would like to have it so when I select a background, the page will lock that background into page, but have the content scroll over top of it. Currently the content scrolls, but the background scrolls with it, leaving an awkward spot where the background no longer exists.

Would anyone know how this effect could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for css's fixed background:
[W3 background definition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

[Here's an example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment) from W3.

Something like this in CSS should work:

```
background: transparent url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
```

And if you want the background stretch/scale 100% width and height of user's screen, you should check [some examples in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background).
See SolidSmile responde [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388817/920648).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a tool like Firebug you can easily figure out which element the background styles are applied to. Then if you have access to (and know how to edit) the theme's stylesheet, you can find that CSS selector and declare `background-position: fixed;`